# Updating cube (writeback) via MDX on SAP BW

Tags: mdx, olap, xmla, sap-bw

Does anybody know if SAP BW supports UPDATE CUBE statement in MDX query? (connection to server established via XMLA)

It returns some generic error and I cannot find any documentation...

Same syntax works well for other providers.

Or is there any other way for writing data to SAP BW cube via MDX?

Thanks for any advice,
Vrata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that SAP BW does not support any write-back - either via MDX (XMLA or ODBO) or any of the OLAP BAPIs.  Larry Sackett has a good book out on the MDX capabilities of SAP BW.